I want to find specific manga where main character reincarnated I don’t remember if it’s into a game or not
More about the manga all I know is reincarnated another world, blonde hair likes alcohol and there’s a guy she likes that is not part of any route and she can only see once or something but now she likes him in the in the other world and she has like really good magic

This Anime Story-Identification is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

It was Osake no Tame ni Otome Game Setting wo Buchikowashita Kekka, Akuyaku Reijou ga Cheat Reijou ni Narimashita (AKA As a Result of Breaking an Otome Game, the Villainess Young Lady Becomes a Cheat!)

Charlotte, who reincarnated as a villainess in an Otome game, started
to avoid the death flag. The goal is to spread the sake that I loved
in this world! However, the juice and holy water that I made for trial
were all nonstandard…
A different world, alcohol fantasy, opened by a cheat girl!



It's great that you found it.  Please don't forget to come back and accept your answer in a couple of days when the system permits it.
